# Handle Date change on primefaces's calendar

Tags: internationalization, calendar, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm working on a JSF 2.0 project using Mojarra, PrimeFaces 2.2.1 and Tomcat 6.x.

My application is internationalized. I use the calendar of primefaces like this:

```
<p:calendar value="#{boxItem.agendaDate}" mode="inline" 
      showOtherMonths="true" styleClass="agendaHBox"
      selectListener="#{boxItem.handleAgendaDateChange}" 
      onSelectUpdate="@form"/>
```

The problem occurs when my locale is different than English and I use selectListener attribute.

For example, it happens when locale is set to Spanish.
When the calendar appears, it is set to the current date: March 2011 24th.
When I click other day like 25th march 2011, the selectListener method is being called, but the date I receive is "Thu May 03 00:00:00 CEST 2012"
and the agenda suddenly changes to March 2012 5th.

The selectListener method is :

```
public void handleAgendaDateChange(DateSelectEvent event)
{
   System.err.println("handleAgendaDateChange = " + event.getDate());
}
```

If I remove selectListener attribute, the calendar behaves correctly (stays as March 2011 and selects 17th), but in this case I have issues handling date changes.

I need some code that will run when user selects a new date in the calendar control and pass it out to backend with Ajax request. How I can do that without the selectListener ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `p:calendar` is buggy if you use it with a different locale than en (as to this [list of open issues related to calendar and locale](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list?can=2&q=calendar%20locale)).

Comment: Yep i was sure it was a bug, but how i can reproduce the ajax ?

Comment: There is a `p:ajax` tag for primefaces. You could give it a try: `<p:ajax update="@form" listener="#{boxItem.handleAgendaDateChange}" />`

Comment: Thanks Matt (especially for the open issues list), that is good to know.

Comment: I will try and make a feedback. Thanks you.